# Wrongly closed SQL parentheses

Tags: sql

I'm fairly new at writing SQL commands so I don't exactly know where I'm going wrong here. I closed all the parentheses, but I still get the following error message:

> Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword AND at [18:5]

Code:

```
goals as (
  select sum(cast(goal as int64)) as goal
  from seed.seed_ads_goals 
   goal_total
    and extract(month from [daterange_start]) = month
)
```

Any hints?

Comment: select ... from ... WHERE ...

Comment: WHERE clause is missing in your sql syntax replace and with WHERE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WHERE` Clause is missing :

```
select sum(cast(goal as int64)) as goal
from seed.seed_ads_goals as goal_total
where extract(month from [daterange_start]) = month
```